# how can i handle the binary data in apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, binaryfiles, spring-camel

i am using apache camel to convert image url to binary data.
because of security area, i cant download image file directly  so i have to use  camel using download file. Client is spring boot.

Server send this binary data and client receive it.and download image file on that client folder.

but how can i handle binary data? i want to download image file between spring boot client and Apache camel

here is my process
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to save the binary data? Who is using Camel in your scenario? The client or the server or both of them? And is your problem on the client or the server side? Please elaborate your question by using the "edit" link below the question. Thanks

Comment: I edited my question. Sever send only binary data and client receive it and download file

Comment: Is it correct that your SpringBoot client currently makes an HTTP request to the server and receives the binary image data? And you ask how to save that image data on the client into a file?

Comment: Yes.that's it. I am sorry to bother you and i am not good at english

Comment: No problem. But you should add the code of your SpringBoot client that calls the server and tries to save the image to your question. And if you get an Exception, add it also. Or if you don't get an Exception try to explain the detailed problem you encounter (for example your code saves the image, but afterwards the image is not present in the filesystem). We can only help you if you help us to understand your situation/problem.